# Received throughput issue with saturated traffic

Tags: network-programming, ns-3

I am using NS3 (v3.13) Wi-Fi model in infrastructure topology configured as follows (simulation file attached):

- Single AP (BSS)
- Multiple STAs (stations)
- Application duration = 10s
- Saturated downlink traffic (OnOffApplication with **OnTime=2s and OffTime=0**) from AP to all STAs
- Phy: 802.11a
- Default YansWifiChannelHelper and YansWifiPhyHelper
- Rate control: ConstantRateWifiManager
- Mobility: ConstantPositionMobilityModel (STAs are positioned on a circle of 2 meters radius around the AP)

Although all is going well, for a high bitrate (saturated traffic), when the number of STAs per BSS increases a lot, some STAs don't receive any BYTE !!

Experiments:

- OnOffApplication DataRate = **60Mb/s**, Phy DataMode=OfdmRate**54**Mbps and 30 STAs, one STA receives packets with a bitrate of 7.2Mb/s and another with 15.3Mb/s (all other 28 STAs don't receive any BYTE)
- OnOffApplication  DataRate = **60Mb/s**, DataMode=OfdmRate**6**Mbps and 30 STAs, one STA receives packets with a bitrate of 1.95Mb/s and another with 4.3Mb/s (all other 28 STAs don't receive any BYTE)

I think that the problem comes from the OnOff Application configurations; how should I configure it to simulate a full buffer downlink traffic?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/wifi-module.h"
#include "ns3/mobility-module.h"
#include "ns3/csma-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/flow-monitor-helper.h"
#include "ns3/flow-monitor-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/gnuplot.h"
#include "ns3/constant-velocity-helper.h"
#include "ns3/integer.h"
#include "ns3/mpi-interface.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>

/**
 *  PARAMETERS
 */
#define StaNb       30
#define Distance    2
#define Duration    10
#define DataRate    90000000
#define PacketSize  1500

#define couleur(param) printf("\033[%sm",param)

using namespace ns3;

class Experiment {
public:
    Experiment();
    void CreateArchi(void);
    void CreateApplis();

private:

    Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> positionAllocAp;
    Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> positionAllocSta;
    Ptr<GridPositionAllocator> positionAllocStaCouloir;
    Ptr<RandomDiscPositionAllocator> positionAllocStaAmphi;

    std::vector<Ptr<ConstantPositionMobilityModel> > constant;

    NodeContainer m_wifiAP, m_wifiQSta;

    NetDeviceContainer m_APDevice;

    NetDeviceContainer m_QStaDevice;

    YansWifiChannelHelper m_channel;
    Ptr<YansWifiChannel> channel;

    YansWifiPhyHelper m_phyLayer_Sta, m_phyLayer_AP;
    WifiHelper m_wifi;

    QosWifiMacHelper m_macSta, m_macAP;

    InternetStackHelper m_stack;
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer m_StaInterface;
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer m_ApInterface;

    Ssid m_ssid;
};

Experiment::Experiment() {

    positionAllocStaCouloir = CreateObject<GridPositionAllocator>();
    positionAllocAp = CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator>();
    positionAllocSta = CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator>();
    positionAllocStaAmphi = CreateObject<RandomDiscPositionAllocator>();

    m_wifi = WifiHelper::Default();

    constant.resize(StaNb + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < StaNb + 1; i++) {
        constant[i] = CreateObject<ConstantPositionMobilityModel>();
    }
}

void Experiment::CreateArchi(void) {

    m_wifiQSta.Create(StaNb);

    m_wifiAP.Create(1);

    m_ssid = Ssid("BSS_circle");

    m_channel = YansWifiChannelHelper::Default();

    channel = m_channel.Create();

    m_wifi.SetStandard(WIFI_PHY_STANDARD_80211a);
    m_wifi.SetRemoteStationManager("ns3::ConstantRateWifiManager", "DataMode",
            StringValue("OfdmRate6Mbps"));

    m_phyLayer_Sta = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default();
    m_phyLayer_AP = YansWifiPhyHelper::Default();

    m_phyLayer_Sta.SetChannel(channel);
    m_phyLayer_AP.SetChannel(channel);

    positionAllocAp->Add(Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

    MobilityHelper mobilityAp;
    mobilityAp.SetPositionAllocator(positionAllocAp);
    mobilityAp.SetMobilityModel("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
    mobilityAp.Install(m_wifiAP.Get(0));

    constant[0]->SetPosition(Vector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

    float deltaAngle = 2 * M_PI / StaNb;
    float angle = 0.0;
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < StaNb; i++) {
        x = cos(angle) * Distance;
        y = sin(angle) * Distance;

        positionAllocSta->Add(Vector3D(x, y, 0.0));

        MobilityHelper mobilitySta;
        mobilitySta.SetPositionAllocator(positionAllocSta);
        mobilitySta.SetMobilityModel("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");
        mobilitySta.Install(m_wifiQSta.Get(i));

        constant[i]->SetPosition(Vector3D(x, y, 0.0));

        angle += deltaAngle;
    }

    m_macSta = QosWifiMacHelper::Default();

    m_macSta.SetType("ns3::StaWifiMac", "ActiveProbing", BooleanValue(true),
            "Ssid", SsidValue(m_ssid));

    m_macAP = QosWifiMacHelper::Default();

    m_macAP.SetType("ns3::ApWifiMac", "Ssid", SsidValue(m_ssid),
            "BeaconInterval", TimeValue(Time(std::string("100ms"))));

    m_APDevice.Add(m_wifi.Install(m_phyLayer_AP, m_macAP, m_wifiAP));

    for (int i = 0; i < StaNb; i++) {
        m_QStaDevice.Add(
                m_wifi.Install(m_phyLayer_Sta, m_macSta, m_wifiQSta.Get(i)));
    }

    m_stack.Install(m_wifiAP);
    m_stack.Install(m_wifiQSta);

    Ipv4AddressHelper address;
    address.SetBase("192.168.1.0", "255.255.255.0");

    m_ApInterface.Add(address.Assign(m_APDevice.Get(0)));

    for (int i = 0; i < StaNb; i++) {
        m_StaInterface.Add(address.Assign(m_QStaDevice.Get(i)));
    }

    Ipv4GlobalRoutingHelper::PopulateRoutingTables();
}

void Experiment::CreateApplis() {

    ApplicationContainer source;

    OnOffHelper onoff("ns3::UdpSocketFactory", Address());
    onoff.SetAttribute("OnTime", RandomVariableValue(ConstantVariable(2)));
    onoff.SetAttribute("OffTime", RandomVariableValue(ConstantVariable(0)));
    onoff.SetAttribute("DataRate", StringValue("500kb/s"));

    for (int i = 0; i < StaNb; i++) {
        AddressValue remoteAddress(
                InetSocketAddress(m_StaInterface.GetAddress(i), 5010));
        onoff.SetAttribute("Remote", remoteAddress);
        source.Add(onoff.Install(m_wifiAP.Get(0)));
        source.Start(Seconds(3.0));
        source.Stop(Seconds(Duration));
    }

    ApplicationContainer sinks;
    PacketSinkHelper packetSinkHelper("ns3::UdpSocketFactory",
            Address(InetSocketAddress(Ipv4Address::GetAny(), 5010)));

    for (int i = 0; i < StaNb; i++) {

        sinks.Add(packetSinkHelper.Install(m_wifiQSta.Get(i)));
        sinks.Start(Seconds(3.0));
        sinks.Stop(Seconds(Duration));
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Experiment exp = Experiment();

    Config::SetDefault("ns3::WifiRemoteStationManager::RtsCtsThreshold",
            StringValue("2346"));

    exp.CreateArchi();

    exp.CreateApplis();

    FlowMonitorHelper flowmon;
    Ptr<FlowMonitor> monitor = flowmon.InstallAll();

    Simulator::Stop(Seconds(Duration));

    Simulator::Run();

    monitor->CheckForLostPackets();
    Ptr<Ipv4FlowClassifier> classifier = DynamicCast<Ipv4FlowClassifier>(
            flowmon.GetClassifier());
    std::map<FlowId, FlowMonitor::FlowStats> stats = monitor->GetFlowStats();
    int c = 0;
    for (std::map<FlowId, FlowMonitor::FlowStats>::const_iterator i =
            stats.begin(); i != stats.end(); ++i) {
        Ipv4FlowClassifier::FiveTuple t = classifier->FindFlow(i->first);
        std::cout << "Flux " << i->first << " (" << t.sourceAddress << " -> "
                << t.destinationAddress << ")\n";
        std::cout << "  Tx Bytes :   " << i->second.txBytes << "\n";
        std::cout << "  Rx Bytes :   " << i->second.rxBytes << "\n";

        couleur("33");
        std::cout << "  Bitrate  :   "
                << i->second.rxBytes * 8.0
                        / (i->second.timeLastRxPacket.GetSeconds()
                                - i->second.timeFirstRxPacket.GetSeconds())
                        / 1000000 << " Mbps\n\n";
        couleur("0");

        if (i->second.rxBytes > 0)
            c++;
    }

    std::cout << "  Number of receiving nodes  :   " << c << "\n";

    Simulator::Destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the medium is too busy.

You need to tuning down onoff datarate e.g 1 mbps. Practically, full buffer 720p video only need no more than 1mbps

You may also check tracing using pcap, ascii or netanim too see either the packet dropping, packet never being send or bug in your code